# React : how to redirect a match of a list of components to sub-path (/templates => /templates/list)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a `React` app, and I do not want to replicate the functionality in all my components to redirect the user to `/<component>/list` if they go to `/<component>` - how would I do this at a higher level?

I have a layout component that would be the place to do it if I were to guess. I have a `getRoutes` method in there that processes a routes definitions file. However, what I would like to do, is provide a list of components that must redirect to that `/<component>/list` path if they go to one of the components in that list:

```
List: ['/templates', '/activities', '/trials']
Visiting:
    /templates: redirects to `/templates/list`
    /activities: redirects to `/activities/list`
    /custom: does nothing, renders CustomComponent
    /trials: redirects to `/trials/list`
    /trials/new: does nothing, renders new method
```

Is this possible? I tried using , but was unsuccessful at capturing items without the path being explicitly defined:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/templates">
        {<Redirect to="/templates/list"/>}
    </Route>
    ...
</Switch>
```

Is there a way to do it something like this? :

```
var paths = ['templates', 'trials'];
getRoutes = routes => {
   return (
      [if path matches /{paths[0..n]]
          <Redirect to={{pathname: /paths[0..n]/list}} />
      [/if]
   );
}
```

I don't think I am on the right track here, but is there something similar to what I am trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can embed logic into JSX with `{}`

```
const list = ['templates', 'activities', 'trials']

return (
  <Switch>
  {list.map(item => (
      <Route 
        path={"/"+item}
        render={() => <Redirect to={"/"item+"/list"}/>}
      />
   )}
 </Switch>
)
```

You'll have to put in a handler for the ones with different logic (like `custom`), so you could restructure the list to use objects instead like:

```
[{path: 'subpath1', component: null}, {path: 'subpath2', component: component2}]
```

and then access the properties accordingly in the map:

```
{
    list.map(item => {
      if (item.component) {
        return (<Route path={"/"+item.path} component={item.component}/>)
      } else {
        return (
          <Route 
            path={"/"+item.path}
            render={() => <Redirect to={"/"item.path+"/list"}/>}
          </Route>
        )
      }
   }) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the following syntax `:paramname(path1|path2)` which will match `path1` and `path2` and name the parameter as `paramname`. Then in `render` you can redirect based on that parameter to wherever you want

```
    <Route
      path="/:toplevel(templates|activities|trials)"
      exact
      render={({ match }) => (
        <Redirect to={`/${match.params.toplevel}/list`} />
      )}
    />
```

All this is mentioned at the [`path` docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/path-string-string) of the react-router-dom

> Any valid URL path or array of paths that [path-to-regexp@^1.7.0](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0) understands.

And in that package's docs see the [custom-match-parameters](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0#custom-match-parameters) section